# What is the difference between Event Handler and Event Listener in Android?

Tags: android

I saw some examples with both of them, but I don't understand where to use which...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080204/are-event-handler-event-listener-and-event-registration-all-referring-to-the-sa)